# Sync contacts to iCloud groups via API

Tags: rest, icloud, contacts, icloud-api

Does Apple offer any API (that doesn't involve an iOS app) that allows contacts to be synced into iCloud and placed into specific groups?

Comment: @Dai edited for clarity...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Reincubate recloud API:
https://reincubate.com/ricloud-api/